# Xamarin android application crash with condition `xref_count == xref_index' not met

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Continuously navigation by some pages of my application causes its crash suddenly, with this message:

```
[] * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mono/metadata/sgen-tarjan-bridge.c:1140, condition `xref_count == xref_index' not met, function:processing_build_callback_data, xref_count is 50 but we added 48 xrefs

[libc] Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31405 (com.MyApp.Beta)
```

This is how I push pages:

```
await ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());
```

I read some threads about related issues and tried adding this argument to android compiler:

`MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=old,nursery-size=128‌​m,soft-heap-limit=512m`

Also tried changing "old" by "new" but no success. Keeps crashing.

This only happens when navigating by 10... 15 pages, if you navigate by few pages it works fine.

What should I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to create a txt file named as enviroment.txt with same arguments mentioned in question:

`MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=old,nursery-size=128‌​m,soft-heap-limit=512m`

You can put this at Properties folder, the same of AndroidManifest.xml and set its build action to AndroidEnviroment, now it should work.